# Splitting integral !!

Tags: real-analysis, integration

i have this simple question that make me really confused : 
let $\phi$ a smooth function with compact support and $p>0,t\ge 0$ and :

\begin{equation}
U_p=
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ccc}
0  & \mbox{if} & x<-pt\\
-2p & \mbox{if} & -pt\leq x<0\\
2p & \mbox{if} & 0\leq x<pt\\
0 & \mbox{if} & x\ge pt
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

i want to calculate this integral :$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}}U_p\partial_t\phi(t,x)dtdx$

the true result in the book is :

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}}U_p\partial_t\phi(t,x)dtdx$=$\int_0^\infty 2p\phi(\frac{x}{p},-x)dx-\int_0^\infty 2p\phi(\frac{x}{p},x)dx$ (and i understood that) now i wanted to calculate it with an other way :

so we have :

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}}U_p\partial_t\phi(t,x)dtdx$= $\int_0^\infty\int_{-pt}^0-2p\partial_t\phi(t,x)dxdt+\int_0^\infty\int_0^{pt}2p\partial_t\phi(t,x)dxdt$ then by Fubini theorem we will have :

$\int_{\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}}U_p\partial_t\phi(t,x)dtdx$= $\int_{-pt}^0\int_0^\infty-2p\partial_t\phi(t,x)dtdx+\int_0^{pt}\int_0^\infty2p\partial_t\phi(t,x)dtdx$=$\int_{-pt}^02p\phi(0,x)dx+\int_0^{pt}-2p\phi(0,x)dx$

and it is not the same result ,so i want to know if there is any mistake somewhere , thanks for any answer !

Comment: **Reality Check:** What is the integration variable for the inner integral doing in the outer bounds of the outer integral?  $$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\int_{-pt}^0 \textsf{stuff}\operatorname d x\operatorname d t \neq \int_{\color{red}{-pt}}^0 \int_0^\infty \textsf{stuff}\operatorname d t\operatorname d x $$

Comment: @Graham Kemp i understand thank you very much i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reality Check:** What is the integration variable for the inner integral doing in the outer bounds of the outer integral?  $$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\int_{-pt}^0 \textsf{stuff}\operatorname d x\operatorname d t \neq \int_{\color{red}{-pt}}^0 \int_0^\infty \textsf{stuff}\operatorname d t\operatorname d x $$

What we have is

$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty\int_{-pt}^0 \textsf{stuff}~\operatorname d x\operatorname d t & =\iint\limits_{(0\leq t< \infty) \times (-pt\leq x< 0)}  \textsf{stuff}~\operatorname d (x, t)
\\[1ex] & = \iint\limits_{(-\infty< x< 0)\times (-x/p\leq t< \infty)}  \textsf{stuff}~\operatorname d (t,x) & \text{iff Fubini's okay}
\\[1ex] & = \int_{-\infty}^0\int_{-x/p}^\infty\textsf{stuff}~\operatorname d t\operatorname d x 
 \end{align}$$

**tl;dr** When Fubini's Theorem is used not only is the order of integration exchanged, the bounds on the inner and outer integrals must be adjusted too.

Comment: just in the unswer i think that when $(-pt\leq x< 0)$ then $t\ge-x/p$ !! because p is positiv

Comment: then it will be $[-x/p,+\infty)$ !!

Comment: doh.  Adjusted  Thanks @M.luffy

Comment: nvrmind and thanks for unswering